# SSRS : how to add an icon with a data region

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

My aim is to have the icon , combined with the results of my dataset

I'm adding an icon in my textbox. The textbox is part of a table , within a list.

[image]

Then I put the name of the image plus the name of my dataset (as you can see below)

```
"mailsocialmedia128" + Fields!MyFieldname.Value
```

[image]

Issue is the icon is **only** appearing when the dataset is empty. But when the dataset is not empty , I have a ... red cross (see picture below).

[image]

How can I have the icon and the data related , inside of the text box?

Thanks in advance for any insights you will be able to provide

Comment: why you are saving your icon into the db? why not in any project folder?

Comment: Hi @KhairulIslam will it make a difference and achieve what I want?

Comment: at least helps to easily retrieve them.

Comment: @KhairulIslam it is ok for what I'm doing. Thanks :) If you have any insights that will help me, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to achieve all of this in a single text box, you can instead create multiple objects within the area.

Right click the text box and select Insert -> Rectangle

You can then insert both a Text box to display the text and a separate Image control to this area, and one won't affect the other.

It could look something like this in design view

[image]

And like this in preview

[image]

Let me know if this is helpful, or if you require further assistance